# What is the expected inputs to Mistral model's embedding layer?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers, mistral-7b

After installing

```
!pip install -U bitsandbytes
!pip install -U transformers
!pip install -U peft
!pip install -U accelerate
!pip install -U trl
```

And then some boilerplates to load the Mistral model:

```
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer, BitsAndBytesConfig,HfArgumentParser,TrainingArguments,pipeline, logging
from peft import LoraConfig, PeftModel, prepare_model_for_kbit_training, get_peft_model
from datasets import load_dataset
from trl import SFTTrainer

import torch

bnb_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(  
    load_in_4bit= True,
    bnb_4bit_quant_type= "nf4",
    bnb_4bit_compute_dtype= torch.bfloat16,
    bnb_4bit_use_double_quant= False,
)

base_model="mistralai/Mistral-7B-v0.1"


model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
        base_model,
        quantization_config=bnb_config,
        torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16,
        device_map="auto",
        trust_remote_code=True,
)
model.config.use_cache = False # silence the warnings
model.config.pretraining_tp = 1
model.gradient_checkpointing_enable()

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(base_model, trust_remote_code=True)
tokenizer.padding_side = 'right'
tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
tokenizer.add_eos_token = True
tokenizer.add_bos_token, tokenizer.add_eos_token
```

We can access the embedding layers (tokenizers -> dense layer output) from:

```
print(type(model.model.embed_tokens))
model.model.embed_tokens
```

[out]:

```
torch.nn.modules.sparse.Embedding
Embedding(32000, 4096)
```

But when I try to feed in some strings it's not the right expected types, e.g.

```
model.model.embed_tokens(tokenizer("Hello world"))
```

[out]:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-66f4114cc3e1> in <cell line: 3>()
      1 import numpy as np
      2 
----> 3 model.model.embed_tokens(tokenizer("Hello world"))

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in embedding(input, weight, padding_idx, max_norm, norm_type, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
   2231         # remove once script supports set_grad_enabled
   2232         _no_grad_embedding_renorm_(weight, input, max_norm, norm_type)
-> 2233     return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
   2234 
   2235 

TypeError: embedding(): argument 'indices' (position 2) must be Tensor, not BatchEncoding
```

or

```
model.model.embed_tokens(tokenizer("Hello world").input_ids)
```

[out]:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-95e95b326f0d> in <cell line: 3>()
      1 import numpy as np
      2 
----> 3 model.model.embed_tokens(tokenizer("Hello world").input_ids)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in embedding(input, weight, padding_idx, max_norm, norm_type, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
   2231         # remove once script supports set_grad_enabled
   2232         _no_grad_embedding_renorm_(weight, input, max_norm, norm_type)
-> 2233     return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
   2234 
   2235 

TypeError: embedding(): argument 'indices' (position 2) must be Tensor, not list
```

And this seems to be the right type it's expecting:

```
model.model.embed_tokens(torch.tensor(tokenizer("Hello world").input_ids))
```

[out]:

```
tensor([[-4.0588e-03,  1.6499e-04, -4.6997e-03,  ..., -1.8597e-04,
         -9.9945e-04,  4.0531e-05],
        [-1.9684e-03,  1.6098e-03, -4.2343e-04,  ..., -2.7924e-03,
          1.1673e-03, -1.0529e-03],
        [-2.3346e-03,  2.0752e-03, -1.4114e-03,  ...,  8.4305e-04,
         -1.0376e-03, -2.0294e-03],
        [-1.5640e-03,  9.3460e-04,  1.8692e-04,  ...,  1.1749e-03,
          3.3760e-04,  3.3379e-05]], device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.bfloat16,
       grad_fn=<EmbeddingBackward0>)
```

**Is there a way to specify the return type when using the `tokenizer()` instead of casting the output of the tokenizer into a torch tensor?**

Comment: Try the `return_tensors='pt'` argument, e.g. `model.model.embed_tokens(tokenizer("Hello world", return_tensors='pt').input_ids)`

Answer (score 0):

Try the `return_tensors='pt'` argument, e.g.

```
model.model.embed_tokens(tokenizer("Hello world", return_tensors='pt').input_ids)
```